# Non https requests getting redirected to 302 while making api call from client side, even https requests go to 302

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Any Request made from API client to server giving 302 for exmaple https://app.ardracloud.com/api/deviceconnect or http://app.ardracloud.com/api/deviceconnect returns 302

```
server {
        listen 66.66.66.66:443 ssl;
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;

        server_name app.ardracloud.com;
        server_name www.app.ardracloud.com;
        server_name ipv4.app.ardracloud.com;


        ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/******;
        ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/******;

        client_max_body_size 134217728;

        access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.ardracloud.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
        error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.ardracloud.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

        root "/var/www/vhosts/ardracloud.com/app.ardracloud.com/public";
        #Error Handling

        error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

        error_page 400 https://app.ardracloud.com:443$request_uri;



         location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

                types { }
                default_type text/plain;

                satisfy any;
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;

                location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
                        deny all;
                }
        }
        #extension letsencrypt end

        location / {
                proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:7081/;
                #proxy_hide_header upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1; proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:7081/ https://app.ardracloud.com/;


        }
        
                location ^~ /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
                alias /var/www/vhosts/ardracloud.com/app.ardracloud.com/public/;
                internal;
        }

        location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:7081;
                proxy_hide_header upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;

        }



        disable_symlinks if_not_owner "from=/var/www/vhosts/ardracloud.com";

        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

}

    map $upstream_http_location $redirect_uri {
            "~https://[^/]+/(?<location_uri>.*)$" "$location_uri";
    }

       upstream origin {
            server app.ardracloud.com;
     }

    server {
        listen 66.66.66.66:80;

        server_name app.ardracloud.com;
        server_name www.app.ardracloud.com;
        server_name ipv4.app.ardracloud.com;

        client_max_body_size 134217728;

        access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.ardracloud.com/logs/proxy_access_log";
        error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.ardracloud.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        }

        location /api {
             return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        }
}
```

@Richard Smit -
The Curl -I response

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 18 Feb 2024 10:39:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://app.ardracloud.com/
```

---

@Richard Smit -
The Curl -I response
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 18 Feb 2024 10:39:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://app.ardracloud.com/

Comment: Use `curl -I` to test your server. Currently, the first URL is returning a 404 status from some PHP script, and the second is returning a 301 status as expected.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 18 Feb 2024 10:39:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://app.ardracloud.com/

Comment: Not sure what you are asking now. Your original question stated that the server returns 302. But now you are stating that it returns 301, which is the expected behaviour according to the second `server` block, which contains two `return 301` statements.

Answer (score 0):

When I do a curl -I -L it gives an 301

curl -i http://app.ardracloud.com/api/deviceconnect -L

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 19:43:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://app.ardracloud.com/api/deviceconnect
HTTP/2 404
server: nginx
date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 19:43:19 GMT
content-type: application/json
x-powered-by: PHP/8.2.15
cache-control: private, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
x-ratelimit-limit: 300
x-ratelimit-remaining: 299
access-control-allow-origin: *
{"success":false,"message":"Validation Error----.","data":"Please Fill Mandatory field"}
```

---

```
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=app.ardracloud.com
*  start date: Feb 15 08:00:40 2024 GMT
*  expire date: May 15 08:00:39 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "app.ardracloud.com" matched cert's "app.ardracloud.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: /api/deviceconnect]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: app.ardracloud.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.88.1]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x562b49732790)
> GET /api/deviceconnect HTTP/2
> Host: app.ardracloud.com
> user-agent: curl/7.88.1
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):

* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/2 404
< server: nginx
< date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 19:52:54 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< x-powered-by: PHP/8.2.15
< cache-control: private, must-revalidate
```

< pragma: no-cache
< expires: -1
< x-ratelimit-limit: 300
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 297
< access-control-allow-origin: *

---

And why do you have a double listen

```
listen 66.66.66.66:443 ssl;
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
```

It's giving a 404 on http2 you might try

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
```